# How do I start a service with my current credentials?

Tags: windows-xp, services

I'm starting a service under WinXP that must be run with **my** credentials.

This works fine as long as I don't have to change my password.

Is there a way to start a service always with my **current** credentials (i.e. domain login)?

Answer (score 3):

No, not with Windows directly (and I don't know of any third party tool).

You will have to create an account (which is sometimes referred to as a service account) for this.

If you set it up with your own account, and change your password, you will not be prompted to update it for services (or even scheduled tasks), they will just not run.